# open closed principle c#

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class

I have 3 classes (1 absrtact(Services), and 2 derivatives). Plus, I have 2 different output formats (UA/EN). And I don't know how remake my code in order it follow a open closed principle. For example, if I want to add a German output format. I will need to edit each class.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
namespace naslidov
{
    public abstract class Services
    {
        public string title;
        public decimal price;

        public Services(string title, decimal price)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public virtual string ToEnglish()
        {        
            return $" ";
        }

        public virtual string ToUkraine()
        {
            return $"";
        }
    }

    public class Food : Services
    {
        public DateTime expirationDate;
        public Food(string title, decimal price, DateTime expirationDate)
            : base(title, price)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
            this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
        }

        public override string ToEnglish()
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{price.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} uan | {expirationDate.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP"))} |------ ";
        }

        public override string ToUkraine()
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{price.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".", ",")} uan | {expirationDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}| ------ ";
        }
    }


    public class HouseholdAppliance : Services
    {
        public int warrantyPeriodInMonths;

        public HouseholdAppliance(string title, decimal price, int warrantyPeriodInMonths)
            : base(title, price)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
            this.warrantyPeriodInMonths = warrantyPeriodInMonths;
        }

        public override string ToEnglish()
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{price.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} uan | ------ |{warrantyPeriodInMonths} ";
        }

        public override string ToUkraine()
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{price.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".", ",")} uan | ------ |{warrantyPeriodInMonths} ";
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter region(UA/EN):");
            string user_input = Console.ReadLine();


            DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2002, 3, 25);
            DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2022, 8, 17);
            DateTime date3 = new DateTime(2005, 1, 10);

            Services first = new Food("apple", 105324660120.58m, date1);
            Services second = new Food("bananas", 3045.21m, date2);
            Services third = new Food("nuts", 308540m, date3);

            Services nofrst = new HouseholdAppliance("television", 25547.54m, 12);
            Services noscd = new HouseholdAppliance("pilosos", 2756854m, 24);
            Services nothir = new HouseholdAppliance("notebook", 32248, 36);


            Services[] fullservices = new Services[] { first, second, third, nofrst, noscd, nothir };
            Console.WriteLine("title    |   price     |   expirationDate   |   warrantyPeriodInMonths");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");

            if (user_input == "EN")
            {
                foreach (Services fullservice in fullservices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fullservice.ToEnglish());
                }
            }
            if (user_input == "UA")
            {
                foreach (Services fullservice in fullservices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fullservice.ToUkraine());
                }
            }
            else if (user_input != "UA" && user_input != "EN")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, wrong input!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific issues that make you think your code *doesn't* follow Open/Closed?

Comment: I think so, for example, if I want to add a German output format. I will need to edit each class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I want to encourage to never refactor without a requirement or goal. If you are trying to refactor this code to make it extensible for something you don't know needs to be extended, you are not only likely to be wasting effort (YAGNI), but you may also end up with code that is harder to change in other ways you might need later.

Thus, for the purposes of this answer, I will assume that the requirement is to make this code extensible (open for extension). And that what you need to extend is the supported formats.

We will start by defining a new <strike>abstract class `Formatter`</strike> interface `IFormat` which will serve as extension point to add new format. Ideally, this `IFormat` should not depend on any specific (concrete, not abstract) `Services`, nor should `Services` know about any specific `IFormat`. That is, we want extending these to be as independent as possible.

Now, what do specific `Services` need to format? I can see in the code that you need to know the format for dates and prices. So let us give methods to format those to `IFormat`:

```
    public interface IFormat
    {
        string FormatDate(DateTime date);

        string FormatPrice(decimal price);
    }
```

*Add any other methods that make sense. I added the minimum for this case.*

We can proceed to implement a formatter for English and one for Ukrane. *Please excuse my naming convention.*

```
    public class FormatterEnglish : IFormat
    {
        public string FormatDate(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP"));
        }

        public string FormatPrice(decimal price)
        {
            return price.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    public class FormatterUkrane : IFormat
    {
        public string FormatDate(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        }

        public string FormatPrice(decimal price)
        {
            return price.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".", ",");
        }
    }
```

Now, let us rework `Services` to use it. It will no longer have one method per format, but one single method that takes a `IFormat` argument:

```
    public abstract class Services
    {
        public decimal price;
        public string title;

        public Services(string title, decimal price)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public abstract string ToString(IFormat formatter);
    }
```

And, of course, we need to implement it in `HouseholdAppliance`:

```
        public override string ToString(IFormat formatter)
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{formatter.FormatPrice(price)} uan | ------ |{warrantyPeriodInMonths} ";
        }
```

And `Food`:

```
        public override string ToString(IFormat formatter)
        {
            return $"{base.title}      |{formatter.FormatPrice(price)} uan | {formatter.FormatDate(expirationDate)} |------ ";
        }
```

To choose our `IFormat`, I suggest a factory method. For example:

```
        private static IFormat? CreateFormatter(string formatName)
        {
            if (formatName == "EN")
            {
                return new FormatterEnglish();
            }

            if (formatName == "UA")
            {
                return new FormatterUkrane();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

*You may also be interested in using type discovery, and specifying the format name in a custom attribute. That is beyond the scope of this answer.*

Finally, you can use it like this:

```
            var formatter = CreateFormatter(user_input);
            if (formatter == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, wrong input!");
                return;
            }

            foreach (Services fullservice in fullservices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fullservice.ToString(formatter));
            }
```

Having a second look at the code, it is possible to extract the <strike>format</strike> template from the `Services`. The `IFormat` would need the template and the data. A solution like [`FormatWith`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FormatWith/) would make that easier. Anyway, I believe this answer addresses the question as it is.

Comment: @Sviatoslav are you asking why it is private? I declared it inside of `Program`, that is all. Are you asking about the quotation mark? That is because it can be null. I wrote it a nullable context. Aside from that, I don't know what are you might be pointing at. Just in case, I'll mention that you could promote it to a factory class, either initialized with a list of Formatter types or with type discovery.

Comment: 1 ANSWER- in what clases i should use (private static Formatter? CreateFormatter(string formatName).....) becase i have error im main : 
Error CS0103 The name 'CreateFormatter' does not exist in the current context, and 1 warning State Warning CS8632 The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.  Please help.

Comment: @Sviatoslav as I said above, I declared it (`CreateFormatter`) inside `Program`. That is where it is used. It could be moved to another class and made public (I suggest a dedicated class `FormatterFactory`) and call it from there. And, about the nullable context, you can either add the annotation `#nullable enable` at the start of the file, which will work if you are using C# 8.0 or newer. Or just remove the quotation mark "?" if you are using an older C#.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, everything works, I just accidentally put this method in the main

Comment: @Sviatoslav You know what? I just realized `Formatter` can be an interface. I think I'll make that edit. Done.